# Java - the scope of keyword this when overriding methods

Tags: java, this, overriding

I am a bit confused about the keyword **this** in Java, I thought **this** is referring to the current object.  In the below example I have created a class A and a class B that extends A.  In the main function when I call the *printMyArray* function it prints 1 2 3 instead of 4 5 6 7.  Is there a way for me to call the *printMyArray* function and print the array that is initialized in B?  So far I can achieve it by having an exact same method in class B as well but I feel it is not the best way to do it.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B b1 = new B();
        b1.printMyArray();
    }
}

class A {
    private int[] numbers = {1,2,3};

    public void printMyArray() {
        for(int i =0; i < this.numbers.length; i++){
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private int[] numbers = {4,5,6,7};
}
```

Comment: *..Is there a way for me to call the printMyArray function and print the array that is initialized in B?..* --> No, because `printMyArray ` exists in A which B is extending.

Answer (score 2):

The code in class `A` can't access the private parts of class `B`.  So when you write `this.numbers` in the code of class `A`, it will refer to the `numbers` field in class `A`.  When you write `this.numbers` in the code of class `B`, it will refer to the `numbers` field in class `B`.

Note that fields don't get overridden in the same way that methods do.  In your example, an object of class `B` will carry around both `numbers` fields.  Which one you get depends on which class contains the code that you're running.

This is why it's generally a terrible idea to use the same name for a superclass field and a subclass field.

Answer (score 2):

You define in each class :

```
private int[] numbers
```

And besides `private` fields are not inherited.
So, referencing `numbers` inside the `A` class will always refer to the `numbers` field declared in the `A` class.
Same logic for referencing `numbers` inside the `B` class that will always refer to the `numbers` field declared in the `B` class.

So here `printMyArray()` will use only the field of the class where this method is declared :

```
   public void printMyArray() {
      for (int i = 0; i < this.numbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(numbers[i]);
      }
   }
```

That's why, its execution prints always :

> ```
> 1,2,3
> ```

---

To solve your problem, you could introduce a public method `getNumbers()` that will be the way to retrieve the `numbers` of each class.
As a public method is overridable, it will now work.

In `A`,  add :

```
public int[] getNumbers() {
    return numbers;
}
```

Update the `printMyArray()` method so that is uses `getNumbers()` and not the `numbers` field.

```
public void printMyArray() {
    for(int number : getNumbers()){
        System.out.println(number);
    }
}
```

And override `getNumbers()` method in `B` so that is uses **its** `numbers` field:

```
private int[] numbers = {4,5,6,7};

public int[] getNumbers() {
    return numbers;
}
```

You could also make `numbers` a `protected` field so that it is inherited in `B` such as :

```
protected int[] numbers = {1,2,3};
```

It spares the `getNumbers()` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the definition of `printMyArray()` method exists in class A. If you want to print objects of class B, then you'll have to override it in class B.

```
...
class B extends A {
    public int[] numbers = {4,5,6,7};

    public void printMyArray() {
        for(int i =0; i < this.numbers.length; i++){
            System.out.println(numbers[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Now you'll get output as : `4 5 6 7`